# Mock a private function of a class which uses member variables in unittest python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a simple class for example

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __check(self):
        if self.age >10:
            "insert into db both age and name"
        else:
            print(self.age)

    def call(self,flag):
        if flag:
            self.__check()
```

Now how do i test the `__check(private function)` using a mock in python

Comment: You don't mock the thing you want to test. If you do that, you can't test it!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
my_child = Child("John", 9)
my_child.call(True)
```

Change the age to above 10 if you want to try the first case in __check().

Comment: I need to use mocks instead of a actual instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Mock the `sys.stdout` to assert the print

```
from StringIO import StringIO

def test_check(self):
    ch = Child('bob', 2)
    self.assertEqual(ch._Child__check(), None)
    with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO) as mock_out:
        ch = Child('bob', 2)
        self.assertEqual(ch._Child__check(), None)
        self.assertEqual(mock_out.getvalue(), '2\n')
```